# Is there a way to see/show user activity in an app?

Tags: google-app-maker

Is there a way to see and (hopefully) display user activity on an App?

Ex:

User 1: Changed Status to In Progress

User 2: Deleted Job #4

Answer (score 2):

For general user activity like visits and page views, you can integrate with Google Analytics by setting an Analytics ID for a particular deployment in the deployment settings. You can also use Analytics custom events:

https://developers.google.com/appmaker/scripting/api/client#Analytics

Another solution would be to have your application write it's own audit log in the [events for your models](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/events), e.g. the "onSave" event.